# Monitor seen as projector and vice-versa

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm running windows 7 ultimate x86 and when I look at my display options I see that my monitor has the number '2' while the TV has '1'.
This also means that my monitor is the 'projector' and TV is the 'monitor' in the Display Presentation Mode (Windows Key + P).

I tried to unplug the HDMI cable (TV) and restart the PC. Doing so, the monitor is '1' and TV is '2' after being plugged in. It only lasts until a restart occures. After restart, the monitor is '2' again.

How to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Does explicitly setting your monitor to be the main display on the Screen Resolution dialog force the change to persist?

Comment: Just for clarification...is there some reason (other than being a bit confusing) that this is actually a *problem*?  That is, is there something that's actually nonfunctional as a consequence?

Comment: No. It always reverts to number 2 but says "This is currently your main display."

Comment: @Shinrai Not a problem but an inconvenience. 40 minutes ago I didn't know this and thought there something wrong with my monitor.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, just wanted to make sure there wasn't a worse problem hiding between the lines.  If you're able to properly set the primary display, this may just be a consequence of the way the video adapter in question numbers the inputs.  It doesn't really *matter* which is 1 and which is 2 (although it can be distracting to have them change regularly)